# Matlab: How to broadcast Hessian derivation for a vector?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, you can get a Hessian matrix by using `hessian(x, v)`, where `x` is scalar function, `v` is vector, and the output is a matrix.

But how to do Hessian from a vector function to a tensor or stacked Hessians?

For example

input: `[x1 x2 x3, ...xn]`

output: `[Hessian(x1); Hesian(x2);...; Hessian(xn)]`

Apparently it can be easily done by using a loop:

```
for i=1:n
    Hess = [Hess; hessian(x(n), x)]
end
```

but how to do more efficiently? Like the broadcasting way in Python, Tensorflow?

Comment: I don't have `hessian` to test, but I guess you may be able to use {:} for your scalar function matrix, something similar to {hessian(x{:},x) }. It might not work but thought it might give you a direction.

Comment: Since `hessian` requires the first input argument to be scalar, I don't think you can do anything more efficient than the loop you have suggested.